# Rails i18n translation for belongs_to validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a User model like this -

```
class User < ActveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group

  validates :email, :user_group, presence: true
end
```

With an en.yml like this -

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          email:
            blank: Enter an email address.
          user_group:
            blank: Please choose a user group.
```

Rails is able to use the presence validation error message for the **email** attribute, but the same doesn't work for the **user_group** attribute. Why so?

**Update**

I should have mentioned earlier - I know validating presence of `user_group_id` instead of `user_group` would work this way, but that isn't as robust.

My form -

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |user_form| %>
    <%= user_form.association :user_group, collection: UserGroup.all, prompt: "Choose a User Group" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have `user_group` attribute or `user_group_id` attribute?

Comment: The database column on the `users` table is `user_group_id` but because of the `belongs_to` association, `user_group` is also an attribute right?

Comment: Does your form works? I mean the value is saved to the DB?

Comment: Yup, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do the value is stored to `user_group_id` column?

Comment: Yes, it gets stored in the `user_group_id` column

Comment: Just read the `simple_form_for` git.That is how it is used in the `simple_form_for`.Normally with `form_for` using `select` that would be `<%= f.select :user_group_id,UserGroup.all, prompt: "Choose a User Group" %>`.So it must be `user_group_id` to be validated not `user_group`.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not agree. Please look at the section for **Associations** in simple_form's [Readme.md](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md). And I have to say it again, I still don't see why the form is relevant here. I have been testing out the validations in the Rails console.

Comment: Please see this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/ASEVn--NBZw I couldn't help more than this.

Comment: @pavan I am indeed following what most people have recommended there. Thanks so much for your time! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I debugged through the source code of Rails and i18n gem and finally figured that the problem was in my en.yml file itself -

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          email:
            blank: Enter an email address.
          user_group:
            blank: Please choose a user group.
          ......
          ......
          ......
          ......
          user_group:
            illegal_name: No special characters allowed
```

As you can see, there were two `user_group` keys (Sorry, I didn't paste the entire en.yml file earlier). So I changed the translations to

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          email:
            blank: Enter an email address.
          user_group:
            blank: Please choose a user group
            illegal_name: No special characters allowed
```

Now this -

```
class User < ActveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group

  validates :email, :user_group, presence: true
end
```

shows the error message given in the translation file.

Answer (score 4):

The automatic validation of a belongs_to relation/association (introduced in 5.x) may get translated via the 'required' key:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          user_group:
            required: "Please choose a user group."
```

No further explicit validates is required (this would trigger the 'blank' key in addition)

Answer (score 1):

> The database column on the users table is user_group_id but because of
>   the belongs_to association, user_group is also an attribute right?

No,you should be validating on `user_group_id` attribute.`user_group` is just a `model name` not an `attribute` here.

Change your `user model` and `en.yml` to look like this

```
#user.rb
class User < ActveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group

  validates :email, :user_group_id, presence: true
end

#en.yml
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          email:
            blank: Enter an email address.
          user_group_id:
            blank: Please choose a user group
```

This should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned earlier, I know that this would work. And there is a specific reason why I validate `user_group` instead of `user_group_id` - When you `validate_presence_of :user_group`, it checks the presence of the `user_group_id` attribute and also that a `user_group` with that `id` exists. The solution you gave only checks the former.

Comment: @akshay_kashain You should make clear that in the question.And i believe that you need `user_group_id` rather than `user_group` here.

Comment: But what about the difference between the two, like I mentioned earlier? - [http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/](http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/)

Comment: I've updated the question with the form code, but I fail to see why that is relevant.